# Reverse engineering LESS from CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, firebug, reverse

How do I trace back ("reverse engineering") CSS in Bootstrap LESS files?

I have made a website using my own Twitter Bootstrap (3.x) template in Joomla 3.4.x. Bootstrap comes with a lot of LESS files from which I 'compile' my bootstrap.min.css file using Crunch. There are more than 40 LESS files and almost 30 mixin LESS files in Bootstrap and they are all 'compiled' to bootstrap.min.css

I've made some changes in the LESS files to style the site to my liking. Besides that I have made a custom.less file that I incorporate in the bootstrap.less file: `@import custom.less`.

After uploading the CSS file to my website I go to the site and work on the CSS with Firebug. I make changes and when I like those, I want to apply the changes in my Bootstrap LESS files, but I find it very hard to trace back where the CSS came from.

Example: in Firebug I find this for the dropdown menu:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
clear: both;
color: #333333;
display: block;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1.7;
padding: 3px 20px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

After a long search I discovered this in dropdowns.less:

```
.dropdown-menu {
...
   // Links within the dropdown menu
  > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: @line-height-base;
    color: @dropdown-link-color;
    white-space: nowrap; // prevent links from randomly breaking onto new lines
  }
  }
```

Of course I could call my custom.less as the last file in my bootstrap.less file and write all the styling overrides in there, but it seems to me that I would create a lot of superfluous code that will ultimately make the site slower.

Is there an easy way to find the LESS code in my LESS files, that is responsible for the CSS that I want to change? Or is there a better 'compiler' that lets me retrace CSS in the LESS files?

Thanx

Thom,
Thomsterdam Web Design

Comment: ["Sourcemaps"](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/live-editing-sass-and-less-in-the-firefox-developer-tools/).

Comment: Looks promising! Can I also use it when the web is 'live' on the internet server and the source files are on my local computer? (I work in Windows 7)

Comment: Well, there're a lot of ways of working with source maps. They may point to original files, may point to a source code injected directly into the final css as comments and so on. So it all depends on how you build them, what you want them to do and what is supported by a particular browser. It's easier to start to work with them (Crunch uses the same reference Less compiler lib so it should have all corresponding options) and see what's possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox DevTools as well as the Chrome DevTools allow to [display and edit the original LESS files using source maps](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/live-editing-sass-and-less-in-the-firefox-developer-tools/).

[image: Option to enable source mapping in Firefox DevTools]

[image: Option to enable source mapping in Chrome DevTools]

Note that Firebug does not offer this feature, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sebastian! I'll dig into this a.s.a.p.